# All-In-One Active Record get() method or ORM (PHP-Active Record)

Tags: orm, codeigniter, activerecord

Is a universal get() method like the one below a good idea

```
function universal_get( $select=NULL, $from=NULL, $where=NULL, $group=NULL, $having=NULL, $order=NULL, $limit=NULL )
{

    // condition checks
    if ( is_string( $select ) OR is_array ( $select ))      { $this->db->select( $select ); }
    if ( is_string( $from ) )                               { $this->db->from( $from ); }
    if ( is_array( $where ) )                               { $this->db->where( $where ); }
    if ( is_string( $group ) OR is_array( $group ) )        { $this->db->group_by( $group ); }
    if ( is_array( $having ) )                              { $this->db->having( $having ); }
    if ( is_array( $order ) )                               { $this->db->order_by( $order ); }
    if ( is_string( $limit ) OR is_int( $limit ) )          { $this->db->limit( $limit ); }

    $result = $this->db->get( $from );

    if ( $result->num_rows() > 0 )     { return $result->result(); }
    else                               { return FALSE; }
}
```

or would an ORM like PHP-ActiveRecord be a better option?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strait forward: No

If you are a programmer then write good code. When I started with CI I was making functions like these all over the place and it very confusing. CI is a framework so basically you are building a framework off of a framework.

Another thing to keep in mind is, you need to always know what going on in the code. Having functions that do too much cause bugs which are hard to trace and restrict usability to specific applications. For instance what if you want to use a join? All properly designed databases will use a join eventually.

Comment: I suspected I was taking it too far and building a framework inside a framework, that's why I decided to post it here and get other programmer's opinion.

Comment: You make a valid point about always needing to know what is going on in the code.  Thanks Michael

Answer (score -1):

I dont think thats a good idea. CI's Active Record takes care of things you dont want to deal with... Add slashes, chaining where and a few others.. just check out their class.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: He is obviously aware of their class, as he is using it in his example.